# PC noisy due to high load - why?

Tags: system-installation, fan

I just installed an ubuntu on my pc(Dell Inspiration I560SR-358, with CPU E5700 3GHz, 4G memory, and NVIDIA GeForce G310).

The pc becomes noisy before that it's quiet with a windows 7 on it.
How come? How to set it to be quiet again in Ubuntu 10.04. 
One of the two cpu usage is always 100%. I think that is the reason.

//re-edit

Everything gets ok after I restart the computer.But the fan is still running which makes it noisy, if i switch to windows 7, it becomes quiet again.

Comment: This is likely a problem with temperature management. We will need more info about your hardware. What computer are you using?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed the Nvidia (closed-source) drivers? Ubuntu uses the Nouveau (open-source) drivers out of the box, which do not support power management yet. This causes the GPU fan to run at 100% - noisy!

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for fans to be noisy when the CPU usage is 100%. It is not normal for CPU usage to be at 100%.

You can try to find the culprit for this CPU usage by going into Sytem->Administration->System Monitor and clicking the 'Processes tab'. You can filter by CPU usage so that the processes using the most CPU are at the top:

[image]

If you tell us this process, we might be able to help you. If you can take a screenshot like the one I have taken and add it to your question, that would be useful.

Comment: .: Everything gets ok after I restart the computer.But  the fan is still running which makes it noisy, if i switch to windows 7, it become quiet again.